# Inherit volumes with extension fields

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I would like to share host `/etc/timezone` file with all docker services from single `docker-compose.yml` file.

I thought, that using [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extension-fields) would be good idea.
I've found [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279662/extend-service-in-docker-compose-3) where extension fields are used to inherit `environment variables`.

So, I've tried it with `docker-compose.yml` like below:

```
x-timezone-volumes:
  &timezone-volumes
  volumes:
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"

services:
  postgres-database:
    image: "postgres:12-alpine"
    hostname: PostgresContainer
    networks:
      backend-network:
    env_file:
      - backups/.env.db
    volumes:
      <<: *timezone-volumes
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and I've this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.postgres-database.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

As i understood from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595406/docker-extension-fields-parser-error), it is because [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is outdated.

Does it mean that I can't use it anymore?
Is there any other solution to inherit volumes?

Comment: The YAML merge key only works for mapping types; under `volumes:` you're trying to use both mapping `k: v` and sequence `- item` syntax at the same time and it doesn't work.  The [Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extension-fields) doesn't suggest an alternative for YAML sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaml merge `<<:` is only supported for mappings. Which is also somewhat indicted by its syntax as its contains a colon.

If you have such an object:

```
x-timezone-volumes:
  &timezone-volumes
  volumes:
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
```

You can reference it like this:

```
services:
  app:
    <<: *timezone-volumes
```

In your case you want to append another item to the volumes array though. So it is not helpful. At max you can reference the individual strings.

```
x-timezone-volumes:
  &timezone-volumes
  volumes:
    - &tz1 "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    - &tz2 "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
```

And then use it like this:

```
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/bar
      - *tz1
      - *tz2
```

You can also mix and match those. Use the first version where there is no additional volume and the second version where you need to add more volumes. For that you could set an anchor name of the entire object and on the array elements.

---

That said, there is the environment variable `TZ` which you also can use to control the time zone of containers.

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
```